# Can't change typeface in ListPreference summary

Tags: android

I am trying to change typeface in Preference Activity and it works great and all title and summary typeface has been changed but the summary of ListPreference is showing in default typeface

```
private void convertPreferenceToUseCustomFont(Preference somePreference) {

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font.ttf");

    Spannable ss;
                if (somePreference.getTitle() != null) {
                    ss = new SpannableStringBuilder(somePreference.getTitle().toString());
                    ss.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , font), 0 , ss.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    somePreference.setTitle(ss);
                }

                if (somePreference.getSummary() != null) {
                    ss = new SpannableStringBuilder(somePreference.getSummary().toString());
                    ss.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , font), 0 , ss.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    somePreference.setSummary(ss);
                }
}
```

And here is customtypefacespan class

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

I am using this way

```
ListPreference language = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
convertPreferenceToUseCustomFont(language);
```

All checkbox and preferncescreen works font but summary of ListPreference has no change

Comment: Same issue. `Typeface` is not applied on summary. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Refer this link for `ListPreference` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060639/change-font-typeface-of-summary-of-listpreference/42065790#42065790.