# Change font typeface of summary of `ListPreference`

Tags: android, listpreference

I tried with [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193405/set-custom-font-for-text-in-preferencescreen/22173268#22173268) to change the typeface of all preferences of `PreferenceScreen`.
It was changed everywhere except summary of `ListPreference`.
Can anyone has an idea how to apply custom font on summary of `ListPreference`?

**UPDATE**

I want to apply my custom font exist on assets folder, not the in-build one. Also  `android:textAppearanceListItemSecondary` required API 21, my app support minimum API 15.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the way to change the font for summary of `ListPreference`.

Override the `onBindViewHolder` method of `ListPreference` to set your custom typeface. Check below custom class.

```
public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {
private String typefaceTitle, typefaceSummary;

public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(typefaceTitle)) {
        TextView titleView = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance().getFont(typefaceTitle));
    }
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(typefaceSummary)){
        final TextView summaryView = (TextView) holder.findViewById(
                android.R.id.summary);
        summaryView.setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance().getFont(typefaceSummary));
    }
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.Preference);

    typefaceTitle = a.getString(R.styleable.Preference_typefaceTitle);
    typefaceSummary = a.getString(R.styleable.Preference_typefaceSummary);

    a.recycle();
}}
```

*attrs.xml*

```
<declare-styleable name="Preference">
    <attr name="typefaceTitle" format="string"></attr>
    <attr name="typefaceSummary" format="string"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Usage in Preference screen.

```
<YOUR_CustomListPreference_PACKAGE_NAME.CustomListPreference
        android:defaultValue="X"
        android:dialogTitle="Dialog Title"
        android:entries="@array/list_item_title"
        android:entryValues="@array/list_item_value"
        android:key="pref_list"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="@string/Preference Title"
        app:typefaceTitle="YOUR FONT NAME"
        app:typefaceSummary="YOUR FONT NAME"/>
```

Hope this help for other.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textAppearanceListItemSecondary">@style/textAppearanceListItemSecondaryCustom</item>
    </style>


    <style name="textAppearanceListItemSecondaryCustom">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
```